# Quadratic variation of a Brownian motion up to time $T$ converges to $T$ in $L^2$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

In Stochastic Calculus for Finance II: Continuous-time Models by Steve Shreve,

> Theorem 3.4.3. Let $W$ be a Brownian motion. Then $[W, W](T) = T$ for
>   all $T > 0$ almost surely.

where $[W, W](T)$ is the quadratic variation of $W$ up to time T
$$
[W, W](T): = \lim_{||\Pi|| \to 0} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} [W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j)]^2
$$
where $$\Pi=[t_0, t_1, \dots, t_n] \text{ and } 0 \leq t_0 < t_1 < \cdots  < t_n = T$$
and
$$||\Pi||= \max_{j=0,\dots, n-1} (t_{j+1} -t_j).$$

One fellow student also says a stronger conclusion is also true, i.e.

> $[W, W](T)$ converges to $T$  in $L^2$ or in $L^p, p>1$, for all $T > 0$.

By "stronger", I mean I heard it implies the original theorem for convergence a.e..

I wonder if there are some texts or online tutorials for proving this stronger conclusion, and/or if you could kindly provide the proof here?

Thanks!

Comment: An $L^2$ convergence argument is given here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59547/quadratic-variation-of-brownian-motion-and-almost-sure-convergence

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Thanks! Does the link talk about convergence in $L^2$ or a.e.? All I see is latter.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer. In the problem description, before he gets to points 1) and 2), the OP gives an argument that concludes "The quadratic variation thus converges in  mean-square to t". This is the $L^2$ convergence.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Thanks! In this case, does convergence in $L^2$ imply convergence in a.e., or the other way around, or neither implies the other?

Comment: Neither implies the other.

Comment: It does *not* converge almost everywhere. Only for certain sequences of partitions do you get a.e. convergence, such as refining sequences of partitions.

Comment: And it will converge in $L^p$ for all $p < \infty$. This implies convergence in probability but not almost sure (everywhere) convergence.

Comment: Also, "$[W,W](T)$ converges to $T$ in ..." is not a meaningful sentence, because $[W,W](T)$ does not refer to the sequence itself, so it isn't something which converges. Rather, it refers to the limit (in probability), which is just a random variable. The theorem quoted is using "almost surely" to refer to equality of the random variable $[W,W](T)$ with $T$, and is not a statement on how the sequence converges.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther: Thanks! "It does not converge almost everywhere", but the quoted theorem from Shreve's book says so. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Ethan: My previous comment should answer that.

Comment: @Ethan: I have to log off now, and can check back tomorrow night. Hopefully my comment clears up some misunderstandings, and I can post a full answer if you want.

Comment: @George: Thank you so much! Yes, it does clarify my misunderstanding. If you could post a full answer, that will be great, and I can upvote it.