# On the evaluation of the mean-square limit: an example

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59547/873016) answer the mean-square limit of a succession of stochastic processes $Q_n$ is calculated in this simple way:

- Check whether the limit of their mean value is finite or not:
  $$\tag{1}\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{ E}[Q_n]=:Q\lt\infty$$
- Make sure that the variance vanishes in the limit:
  $$\tag{2}\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{Var}[Q_n]=0.
  $$

If both $(1)$ and $(2)$ are realized, then $Q$ is shown to be the mean square limit of $Q_n$. **Is this a general strategy? According to what theorem?**

*UPDATE*. As @Adam pointed out, this strategy provides sufficient but not necessary conditions. As an example, consider the integral

$$ Q:=\int_{t_0}^t\mathrm{d}W_s$$
this is by definition the mean-square limit of
$$
Q_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\bigg(W(t_i)-W(t_{i-1})\bigg)=W(t)-W(t_0)
$$
where $t_n=t$, and $t_i-t_{i-1}=(t-t_0)/n$. But then, according to the definition of wiener process, $W(t)-W(t_0)\sim\mathcal{N}(0, t-t_0)$, so
$$
\mathrm{E}[Q_n]=0,\\ \mathrm{Var}[Q_n]=t-t_0\nrightarrow 0 \quad \mathrm{as} \quad n\to\infty
$$

and yet, $W(t)-W(t_0)$ is supposed to be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For equation (1) to make sense, the limit $Q$ must be a constant; I'll write it as $q$ to avoid confusion. We then have

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[(Q_n-q)^2] &= \mathbb E[(Q_n - \mathbb E Q_n + \mathbb E Q_n - q)^2]\\
&=\mathbb E[(Q_n - \mathbb E Q_n)^2 + 2(Q_n - \mathbb E Q_n)(\mathbb E Q_n - q) + (\mathbb E Q_n - q)^2]\\
&=\mathbb V \mathrm{ar}[Q_n] + (\mathbb E Q_n - q)^2\\
&\to 0;
\end{align*}$$
thus the $Q_n$ have mean-square limit $q$.

Comment: Why does $Q$ have to be constant? Shouldn't $\displaystyle Q(t)<\infty\ \forall\,t$ be enough?

Comment: I'm saying it's a constant for fixed $t$; it's not random. @ric.san

Comment: Isn't there a way to make sense of $(1)$ if $Q$ is a random variable (just depending upon $t$ but not $n$)?

Comment: Well, $Q$ is a limit of expectations, so as written it's non-random by definition. If you mean something else, you'd have to say what. @ric.san

Comment: Ok, but then I don't know how to make sense of the example I added some hours ago

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here? Yes, it's possible to converge in mean square without satisfying (1) and (2); the conditions are sufficient but not necessary. @ric.san

Comment: Aren't there necessary and sufficient conditions? Otherwise, how can one find such a limit? By guessing?

Comment: There are lots of ways to show mean square convergence; the approach usually depends on the problem. @ric.san

Comment: I see... thanks for your patience. My original problem was actually to find a criterium to evaluate $$\int_{t_0}^t\mathrm{d}W_s \qquad \mathrm{and} \qquad\int_{t_0}^tW_s\,\mathrm{d}W_s$$ but I think that's another question.